# JQuery when() then() results in missing ajax responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax, deferred, responsetext

This has me stumped.  I have an array of urls (for data) which I need to pull into the page and process the results once all are loaded.  I am attempting to use JQuerys Deffered functionality to ensure that all of the ajax calls have completed before I process the results.  As soon as I introduced it (the when().done() functionality), my responseText magically disappeared.

My simplest example:

```
$.when([$.ajax("pathToData")]).done(
    function(results) {
        console.log(results[0]);               //object with a responseText attribute
        console.log(results[0].responseText);  //undefined !!!
    }
)
```

I suspect I am missing something simple, but the more I read the documentation the more this looks correct.  I'm hoping someone else can spot the issue easily and point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tried this, and I get the same result.  What is going on?  http://jsfiddle.net/39mHw/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weird behaviour you're seeing is a limitation of the `console`, and actually nothing to do with your code.

The resolution of the properties of the object are deferred until you expand the `Object` in the `console`. By that time the AJAX request has completed and `responseText` is available. However, the value of `results[0].responseText` is resolved immediately as `undefined`.

If you did:

```
$.when([$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {json: '{"a":12}'}
})]).done(function(results) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results[0])); //object with a responseText attribute
    console.log(results[0].responseText); //undefined !!!
})​
```

You'll see:

```
{"readyState": 1}
undefined
```

Instead.

---

As to how to solve your problem; I've never known `$.when()` to accept arrays, nor does the documentation say it does. Because of this, `when()` seems to be executing the `done()` immediately, as the array is not a deferred (per the docs):

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

Instead pass your AJAX request(s) as separate parameters, as shown in the docs:

```
$.when($.ajax('a'), $.ajax('b')).done(function (a, b) {
  // a & b = [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ]
});
```

As such:

```
$.when($.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {json: '{"a":12}'}
}), $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {json: '{"b":12}'}
})).done(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a[2].responseText);
    console.log(b[2].responseText);    
})​;
```

There you get:

```
{"a": 12}
{"b": 12}
```

... and an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39mHw/2/

Comment: You're right in about `$.when` not accepting arrays.  I thought it did too.  Good job figuring out the issue :-)

Comment: If he does have an array which I guess he can use `$.when.apply($, yourArray).done(...)`

Comment: apply allowed me to work around when() not taking an array of deffered, which I had found in some part of the documentation.  Unfortunately I lost that reference or I'd point it out for future correction.  Thanks for the rapid help, and kudos for explaining the reason that console was showing conflicting information.  I'm no stranger to concurrent software development, and this is a good example of how tricky it can be.

Answer (score 0):

What gets set to `results` is an array representing 3 things - the textStatus (i.e. "success"), statusText, and jqXHR object - in that order.

You need to access array position 2 to get jqXHR object which has the `responseText` attribute.  So simply change your index values like this:

```
$.when($.ajax("pathToData")).done(
    function(results) {
        console.log(results[2]);               //object with a responseText attribute
        console.log(results[2].responseText);  //undefined !!!
    }
)
```

Note that I have removed the array brackets around the `ajax()` function call here.

Here is an exact example from jQuery `when()` page ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when ):

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   if ( /Whip It/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
      alert("First page has 'Whip It' somewhere.");
   }
});
```

Comment: `results` only contains 1 element.

Comment: Mike, that works when the argument to the when() method is an ajax request.  However, in this case I am passing an array of ajax requests.  The anonymous callback function within done is only being passed a single object parameter, and it is an array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Actually you are correct in that he has array brackets around the `ajax()` call for some reason in his original question which apparently I glanced over at first.  I have removed those in my answer and noted as such.

Comment: In the case of using that array notation, my guess is you would have to go one level deeper like `results[0][2].responseText`. Problem though is how that actually works since you are no longer passing a Deferred object (or comma-separated list of Deferred objects) to the `when()` function.

Comment: This is still wrong.  When done this way, `.done` acts like the `success` function you would pass to `$.ajax`, meaning it's passed 3 params, not just 1.

Comment: The array brackets are necessary, as I will have more than one ajax call to make.  I removed the other calls within the example just to keep it short.
I tried results[0][2].responseText, and that does not work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The example at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ show a single parameter passed per passed Deferred object, with each of those parameters being an array with three elements, the last of which is the actual jqXHR object which he is interested in.

Comment: My example says otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/39mHw/1/  (P.S. That example you're pointing out uses `.then`, not `.done`)

Comment: @allenru The examples at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ show use of comma-seperated list of Deferred objects parameters, not an array of Deferred objects (i.e. Object resulting from AJAX calls). I am not sure if an array of Deferred objects is supported (I can't find anywhere that suggests it is).

Comment: @MikeBrant you are correct. It needs to be a comma-seperated list of Deferreds. In order to use an array, you can call `when()` using `apply()` like this: `$.when().apply(null,ArrayOfDeferreds)`

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have just added teh exact example from the jQuery `when()` page to my answer above.  This example uses multiple ajax calls and `when().done()`

Comment: @MikeBrant: Your `$.when($.ajax("pathToData")).done(` example is still wrong, though.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: You mean: `$.when.apply($, ArrayOfDeferreds)`

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah, that's what I meant. =)

Comment: @RocketHazmat How is my example wrong?  It is almost exactly the same as the jQuery documentation example only with use of a single ajax request, and calling the parameter to `done()` function definition as `results` instead of `a1` (and of course not doing a regex test on the response content).

Comment: @MikeBrant: Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/39mHw/3/ When called with 1 AJAX request, `.done` acts like `success`, which means it's passed 3 params, not 1.